# XSLT Transformation add new node

Tags: xslt

I've a XSLT Transformation shown below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/configuration">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:element name="system.diagnostics">
        <trace autoflush="true">
          <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics" name="AzureDiagnostics"></add>
          </listeners>
        </trace>
      </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
 <xsl:template match="configuration">    
       <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:element name="location">
        <xsl:attribute name="path">securfolder1</xsl:attribute>
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </xsl:element>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting that above should produce below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true">
         <listeners>
            <add name="AzureDiagnostics"
                 type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics"/>
         </listeners>
      </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
   <location path="securfolder1">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

But some reason it's not working. You may ask why you I have two template match. The problem is that top section below provided by third party which we can't change.

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
          <xsl:element name="system.diagnostics">
            <trace autoflush="true">
              <listeners>
                <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics" name="AzureDiagnostics"></add>
              </listeners>
            </trace>
          </xsl:element>      
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
```

Below is the INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: You forgot to show the input XML.

Comment: Sorry added input xml.

Comment: You cannot have two templates that match the same node and expect both of them to run. Only one of them will run (`<xsl:template match="/configuration">` in your case). My question is: Obviously you *can* modify the XSLT file and add your own template, so why do you say that you cannot change the other template?

Comment: above xslt is the one I modified and not working. Thanks Tomalak. I thought first template will run and second will apply on top.

Comment: No, the one with the most specific match expression for any given node will run. A bit like CSS selectors, but templates are never additive. Only one can win.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you were to apply both templates, they both output a **configuration** element, which would result in your output having two **configuration** elements, and not just the one you require.

However, I can think of a rather hacky solution, if you really, really can't get the first template changed.

What you could do is create a template that matches the document element, which is a level above the root **configuration** element, and so will be matched first

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Then, within this template, you can apply their configuration matching template, but store the result in a variable

```
 <xsl:variable name="theirs">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="configuration" />
 </xsl:variable>
```

I am assuming you are using a Microsoft platform here, given this it very much a Microsoft application configuration file. This means you should have access to Microsoft's extension functions. You will need these because the **theirs** variable is a "result tree fragment", but to get this solution to work you will need to access it as a node-set.

Essentially, what you can do in your own template (the one that now matches `/`), is this:

```
<configuration>
    <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($theirs)/configuration/*" />
    <!-- You own elements -->
</configuration>
```

In other words, copy the elements the first template produces, then output your own.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/configuration">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         <xsl:element name="system.diagnostics">
            <trace autoflush="true">
               <listeners>
                  <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics" name="AzureDiagnostics"/>
               </listeners>
            </trace>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="theirs">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="configuration" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <configuration>
         <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($theirs)/configuration/*"/>
         <xsl:element name="location">
            <xsl:attribute name="path">securfolder1</xsl:attribute>
            <system.web>
               <authorization>
                  <deny users="*"/>
               </authorization>
            </system.web>
         </xsl:element>
      </configuration>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following is output

```
<configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true">
         <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics" name="AzureDiagnostics"/>
         </listeners>
      </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
   <location path="securfolder1">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```